# Finding whether bit position is set in C#

Tags: c#, binary, bit

I'm getting quite confused here.

If I have a number, let's call it 16 here, and I want to check if a particular bit is set. I would do the following:

```
if (16 & (2 ^ bitPosition) == (2 ^ bitPosition))
```

Right?

Why then, for bitPosition = 2, is that statement returning true? Shouldn't it be false, as only bitPosition = 4 is true in that case?

My understanding was:

```
Bit|Val
0  |1
1  |2
2  |4
3  |8
4  |16
5  |32
6  |64
7  |128
```

I've never worked with this kind of thing before and it's baffling me.

Comment: ^ is not power its xor operator.

Comment: Change `2 ^` to `1 <<`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^` operator is bitwise XOR in C#.
Try to check as follows:

```
if ((value & (1 << bitPosition)) != 0)
```

Where `<<` is a bit shift left operator that is, in fact, exponentiation of 2.

Comment: Thank you yes this worked! Doh!